# I am trying to upload test cases in CA Rally using Python library pyral, test cases are uploaded successfully but not able to set Owner for test case

Tags: python, rally, testcase, pyral

I am trying to upload test cases in CA Rally using Python library pyral, test cases are uploaded successfully but not able to set Owner for test case

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset

options = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg.startswith('--')]
args = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg not in options]

server, user, password, apikey, workspace, project = 
rallyWorkset(options)


rally = Rally(server='rally1.rallydev.com', 
      apikey="************************",
      workspace='***', project='*****',
      server_ping=False)
response = rally.get('UserStory', fetch = True, projectScopeDown=True, 
query = 'FormattedID = *****', instance=True)
target_project = rally.getProject()
testcase_fields = {
 "Project"     : target_project.ref,
 "WorkProduct" : response.ref,
 "Name"        : "Fifth Test Case",
 "Owner"       : "myDisplayName" or "myUserName",(Nothing Works)
 "Description" : "This is a python integration test",
 "Method"      : "Manual",
 "Type"        : "Acceptance",
 "Pre Conditions"  : "This is Pre-Condition",
 "Validation Input"  : "This is validation input",
 "Validation Expected Result"  : "This is validation expected result",
 "Post Conditions"  : "This is post condition"
}
testcase = rally.put('TestCase', testcase_fields)
print(testcase.details())
```

Getting Error if using Owner Field:

```
File "<ipython-input-57-c146d75c3723>", line 51, in <module>
    testcase = rally.put('TestCase', testcase_fields)

File "C:\Users\achaube2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyral\restapi.py", line 1024, in put
    raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem)

RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Cannot parse object reference from "myDisplayName"

Test Case is uploaded successfully if i remove the Owner Filed in above code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 'user' show be a ref to a user-object.

Comment: can you please explain little bit more, i have already tried to use rally.getUserInfo() and rally.getAllUsers(workspace="***") but not able to achieve anything from these

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

The "Owner" field is a reference to the User object. You will need to set the Owner field with a reference to the ObjectID of the owner user object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your user object first like:

```
user_req = rally.getUserInfo(username="name@domain.com")
user = user_req[0]
```

Then, you can use it for referencing in TestCase like:

```
"Owner"       : user.ref
```